# PHP date function returning wrong date, how can I specify my time zone?

Tags: php, date, time

```
<?php echo date('m/d/Y',time());?>
```

echos

```
07/13/2013
```

when it should echo

```
07/12/2013
```

Is there a server config I should change and if there is where could I find it? Thank you My time zone is (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)

Comment: I'm almost certain not a keystroke of research was put into this before you asked this question. -1

Comment: Sorry, it's because I tired America/Portland, and it gave me an error, and I couldn't find a list of cities that were supported, so I thought it didn't work, but just I tried Los_Angeles, and it worked. Sorry for the noobish question!

Comment: Sieu Phan: A search for "php timezones" on Duck Duck Go and Google resulted in the first entry http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: oop, I tend to overthink the problem and throw in a buncha other terms too. D:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```