# How do I properly configure the PHP date?

Tags: php, date

I though I found some answers to this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626364/php-date-function-returning-wrong-date-how-can-i-specify-my-time-zone/41112831#41112831) related to my one, but they did not work for me. My problem for the last 5 days is, that I'm getting wrong date while running the following code. Today is 12/13/2016, but it is showing 11/17/2016. I'm not getting any solution on the internet.

```
<?p echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>
```

Even I've set the time zone to `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` 
So I'm looking for a PHP configuration or any other solution.

Comment: Are you getting an error in this line >> `<?p echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>` Does your code have `<?p` instead of `<?php ` or is it a typo here?

Comment: Since , the gap between the date is more than a day in ur case , its mean there no timezone problem bec it have only one day difference (+1 day or -1day) . {unless if you yourselft have not change your server timezone} there must be some problem with the variable . please provide your code

Answer (score 1):

use `<?php` in place of `<?p`, and the most important thing is that PHP takes date, time and timezone from your server then changes it according your format. Be sure that your server's date, time and timezone is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<?p` instead of `<?php`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Guys,for giving late response, thanks for all your responses. Actually the problem was from PHP server itself. After contacting the server admin they solved the problem. Again many many thanks for your responses.