# Php date() function add extra day

Tags: php, date, sysdate

I'm trying to echo out the current system date. But it outputs the date of tomorrow. I double check the System Date and tested changing the date. Still it adds 1 extra day when echoing out.

What could be the problem?

```
<?php
    echo date("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Comment: Did you check your php.ini for the set timezone? It should be under date.timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date function returning wrong date, how can I specify my time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626364/php-date-function-returning-wrong-date-how-can-i-specify-my-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

If not specified, 2nd argument for `date()` defaults to current Unix timestamp - amount of seconds since 01.01.1970, 0:00 GMT.

You can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set your timezone, or manually convert the date to correct one: `date($format, time() + $difference)`.